# How to Play a Video in a Vuforia Image Target in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

How can I have a video play in a Vuforia Image target using Unity? The Vuforia core samples seem overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to over-complicate it. Just use a Quad, and a VideoPlayer.

1. Create a Quad as a child of the Image target
2. Create a VideoPlayer as child of the Quad. Be sure to set the **Video Clip** property to the video you want to play

The setup should look like this:

[image: Setup]

3. Set the **Renderer** property of the VideoPlayer to the previously created Quad
4. Uncheck the **Play on Wake** property on the VideoPlayer
5. Use this script to Play and Stop the VideoPlayer. Place the script on the Image Target

   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using UnityEngine;
   using UnityEngine.Events;
   using Vuforia;

   public class ImageTargetBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
   {
       private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
       public UnityEvent myStartEvent;
       public UnityEvent myStopEvent;

   ```
   void Start()
   {
       mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
       if (mTrackableBehaviour)
       {
           mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
       }
   }

   public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                   TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                   TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
   {
       if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
           newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
           newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
       {
           // When target is found
           myStartEvent.Invoke();
       }
       else
       {
           // When target is lost
           myStopEvent.Invoke();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
6. Now make the VideoPlayer Start and Stop in the Component Inspector of this script

[image: Image Target Behaviour Script]

Comment: TIP: You can use this above script to START and STOP anything when the Image Target is detected/undected. For example Audio